# Pytorch how to increase batch size

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, pytorch, onnx

I currently have a tensor of torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 224]) but I need it to be input shape [32, 3, 256, 224].  I am capturing data in real-time so dataloader doesn't seem to be a good option.  Is there any easy way to take 32 of size torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 224]) and combine them to create 1 tensor of size [32, 3, 256, 224]?

Comment: `torch.cat` on a list of 32 tensors

Comment: Yes, thank you.  I was doing torch.concatenate but thats a numpy thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are probable using jit model, and the batch size must be exact like the one the model was trained on.

```
t = torch.rand(1, 3, 256, 224)
t.size() # torch.Size([1, 3, 256, 224])
t2= t.expand(32, -1,-1,-1)
t2.size() # torch.Size([32, 3, 256, 224])
```

Expanding a tensor does not allocate new memory, but only creates a new view on the existing tensor, and you get what you need. Only the tensor stride was changed.